# Как сгруппировать результат запроса

Tags: javascript, websqldatabase

Делаю todo на JS и WebSQL. Структура таблицы в БД: id | content | date (в формате mysql - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS). Код такой:

```js
database.transaction(function(tx) {     
  tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM todo", [], function(tx, result) {
   
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
     
      var id = result.rows.item(i).id;
      var content = result.rows.item(i).content;
      
      var bddate = result.rows.item(i).date;      
      var date = new Date(bddate);      
      var day = date.getDate(); // день

     // вывод
     
    }
  });
});
```

Как вывести не целым списком, а сгруппировать по дням?

UPD: Попытался, но не работает

```js
tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM todo ORDER BY DATE", [], function(tx, result) {
  // до тех пор пока есть данные
  var arrDay = [];
  var startDay = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {

    var bddate = result.rows.item(i).date;

    var date = new Date(bddate);
    var day = date.getDate(); // день

    if (startDay == null) {
      startDay = day;
    }

    if (startDay != day) {
      console.log(arrDay); // вывод дневного массива
      arrDay.length = 0;
      startDay = day;
    }

    // добавляем в дневной массив
    arrDay.push(result.rows.item(i));
  }
});
```

Comment: А что значит "сгруппировать по дням", вот есть у нас две записи за один день с разным временем, что при выводе "сгруппированных" данных должно быть с содержимым content ?

Comment: Не, допустим div 25 число - в ul-li все заметки этой даты, за 26 div - все заметки за этот день и тд. Чтобы дни различить можно было.

Comment: тогда добавить к запросу `order by date` что бы записи из БД по порядку дат шли и дальше дописываете данные в div для текущего дня, текущий день запоминаете в переменно и на следующем цикле если день не изменился дальше допечатываете, если изменился завершаете текущий div и начинаете следующий

Comment: Запрос дописал, но с циклом не совсем понятно.

Comment: Вообще не работает ? С виду все правильно написано, правда работу с БД на JS я никогда не видел, так что не могу быть уверен на счет правильности именно этой части. Есть только одно замечание, для последней даты надо после цикла напечатать массив если он не пуст